# C++ / Python Equivalent of Matlab's num2hex

Tags: python, c++, matlab, hex, floating-point-conversion

Is there a function in C++ or Python that is equivalent to MATLAB's [num2hex](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2hex.html) function?

Python's `float.hex` and `int.hex` functions do not give the same result as MATLAB's `num2hex` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### MATLAB

```matlab
% single
>> num2hex(single(1))
ans =
3f800000

% double
>> num2hex(1)
ans =
3ff0000000000000
```

#### Python

```python
>>> x = 1.0

# 32-bit float
>>> hex(struct.unpack('!l', struct.pack('!f',x))[0])
'0x3f800000'

# 64-bit float
>>> hex(struct.unpack('!q', struct.pack('!d',x))[0])
'0x3ff0000000000000L'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Unfortunately, this does not work for negative numbers (32-bit float, 64-bit float) since the minus symbol is included after the unpacking operation. By changing 'l' to uppercase 'L' and 'q' to uppercase 'Q' unsigned representations are used instead.
2. Furthermore, the hexadecimal numbers are displayed in big-endian format. In order to have little-endian format use '<' instead of '!'.

   ```
   # 32-bit float
   >>> hex(struct.unpack('<L', struct.pack('<f', x))[0])

   # 64-bit float
   >>> hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', x))[0])
   ```