# What causes this arithmetic discrepancy between numpy and MATLAB and how can I force either behavior in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matlab, ieee-754

I tried to normalize a probability distribution of the form $p_k := 2^{-k^2}$ for $k \in {1,\dots,n}$ for $n = 8$ in numpy/Python 3.8 along the following lines, using an equivalent of MATLAB's num2hex a la [C++ / Python Equivalent of Matlab's num2hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790722/). The sums of the normalized distributions differ in Python and MATLAB R2020a.

If $n < 8$, there is no discrepancy.

**What is going on, and how can I force Python to produce the same result as MATLAB for $n > 7$?** It's hard for me to tell which of these is IEEE 754 compliant (maybe both, with a discrepancy in grouping that affects a carry[?]) but **I need the MATLAB behavior.**

I note that there are still discrepancies in rounding between numpy and MATLAB per [Differences between Matlab and Numpy and Python's `round` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982650/) (which I verified myself) but not sure this has any bearing.

```
import numpy as np
import struct # for MATLAB num2hex equivalent below
n = 8
unnormalizedPDF = np.array([2**-(k**2) for k in range(1,n+1)])
# MATLAB num2hex equivalent a la https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790722/
num2hex = lambda x : hex(struct.unpack('!q', struct.pack('!d',x))[0])
hexPDF = [num2hex(unnormalizedPDF[k]/np.sum(unnormalizedPDF)) for k in range(0,n)]
print(hexPDF)
# ['0x3fec5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3fbc5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3f6c5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3efc5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3e6c5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3dbc5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3cec5862805436a4', 
#  '0x3bfc5862805436a4']
hexPDFSum = num2hex(np.sum(unnormalizedPDF/np.sum(unnormalizedPDF)))
print(hexPDFSum)
# 0x3ff0000000000000
```

Here is the equivalent in MATLAB:

```
n = 8;
unnormalizedPDF = 2.^-((1:n).^2);
num2hex(unnormalizedPDF/sum(unnormalizedPDF))
% ans =
% 
%   8×16 char array
% 
%     '3fec5862805436a4'
%     '3fbc5862805436a4'
%     '3f6c5862805436a4'
%     '3efc5862805436a4'
%     '3e6c5862805436a4'
%     '3dbc5862805436a4'
%     '3cec5862805436a4'
%     '3bfc5862805436a4'
num2hex(sum(unnormalizedPDF/sum(unnormalizedPDF)))
% ans =
% 
%     '3fefffffffffffff'
```

Note that the unnormalized distributions are exactly the same, but the sums of their normalizations differ by a single bit. If I use $n = 7$, everything agrees (both give 0x3fefffffffffffff), and both give the same results for $n < 7$ as well.

Comment: If your code depends on specific floating-point rounding errors, you’re doing it wrong. This is not only about differences in computation order, but also about differences in floating-point operations in different chips. Don’t try to get bit-level equality between programs, make your algorithm robust against rounding errors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo -- I am doing it right, but I agree with you in general. The MATLAB version (with direct summation) is correct. I am computing bounds on an (at times astronomically large) expected value and have proved several lemmas underlying these bounds. I wasn't looking for bit-level equality between programs but the Python np.sum() stuff was giving me a denominator of 0. If Python behaved properly and called the result Inf I probably would never have noticed any of this in the first place, but instead I got NaNs for my bounds that were totally unacceptable.

Comment: PS- Direct summation is numerically ideal because the thing I'm summing is already sorted in descending order to make the numerics nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual, [numpy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) uses [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation) to get more precision. Another common algorithm is [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

Anyway, I wouldn't count too much on Numpy and MATLAB giving the same result up to the last bit, as there might me operation reordering if computations are made in parallel. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963026/matmul-result-not-equal-with-explicit-calculation-for-double-precision/68968692#68968692) for the kind of problem that can arise.

However, we can cheat a little bit and force Python to do the sum without the extra precision:

```
hexPDFSum = num2hex(np.sum(np.hstack((np.reshape(unnormalizedPDF / np.sum(unnormalizedPDF), (n, 1)), np.zeros((n, 1)))), 0)[0])
hexPDFSum
'0x3fefffffffffffff'
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I can't tell what MATLAB uses, though it seems likely that it's direct summation in this case as suggested by https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/550-compensated-summation-in-sum. Summation is apparently done with more finesse for large arrays 
as https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2021/09/07/a-faster-and-more-accurate-sum/ spells out.

Comment: I got Python to agree with MATLAB by using sum instead of np.sum as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @SHuntsman I added a way to get the same result: by forcing the sum on a dimension that is not the leading one. Probably not efficient, but if you need it, you have it.